# How do I get the element containing clicked text in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, textnode

I would like to replace the text on pages when I click on the text or even just replace the single word clicked on. I have tried a top down approach selecting all elements in the DOM, filtering out the textNodes, wrapping each with tags and adding a click event handler to each tag. But this is far too slow and inefficient particularly on very large and dynamic sites.

I only need to replace the text that was clicked. Is there a bottom up way of doing this starting from the `event.target`? How do I find the closest textNode to the `event.target`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, you can just do the following; for more info see **[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)**

```
$(document).click(function(event) {     
    textNodes = $(event.target).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });

    textNodes.each( function() {
         $(this).replaceWith("New Text");
    });
})
```

Comment: The way that you're doing it is somewhat convoluted, but here's how it would work: http://jsfiddle.net/qqm9a/3/

Comment: I changed my question to not use `div`s at all, and the code is in JSFiddle, try it. It works for your span, div, whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Jquery's .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) ?

**Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.